# How to change CSS on UI elements after an .ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a Symfony app for which I'm uisng a Bootstrap front end.

I'm trying to use ajax to toggle the state of an item in the database.  Whenever `a.isActive` is clicked, my `/admin/toggleProgramActive` route should be called.  This route contains code to update the database appropiately.  When successful, `.done` ought to be called, and the jQuery therein should run (changing the styling on some elements).

However, here's what's happening instead:  My Symfony route is being called, and the database is being updated.  But... jQuery never triggers the UI changes.

Here's the relevent code:

HTML:

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr class="bg-primary no-hover">
        <th ...>
            <div>
                <a href="#" 
                   class="isActive" 
                   data-program-id="{{ program.programId }}">
                    <span class="fa fa-power-off {{ active  ?  'active'  :  'non-active' }}" > </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()  {
    $(".isActive").on('click', function()  {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  "/admin/toggleProgramActive",
            data: {"id": $(this).data('program-id')}
        })
            .done(function() {
                element.closest("tr").css('background-color', '#FF6600');
                element.closest("tbody").effect("highlight", {}, 600, function()  {
                    $(this).find("tr.bg-primary").css('background-color', "#337AB7")
                });
            })
    });
});
```

I know that `.done` is being called.  If I place a `console.log(element)` after `.done(function() {` I can see it returning `[a.isactive]` in the Chrome console.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  How should I go about changing CSS after an ajax call?

Comment: use .success instead of .done.

Comment: @spooky from (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) : `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`

Comment: @mcmurphy did you check my answer?

Comment: @Dekel thanks... didn't really follow your answer.  Ajax is kinda new to me.  I was not trying to change the .isActive, but rather the tr and tbody above it in the DOM.  (see my edited HTML).

Comment: @mcmurphy regarding the ajax - the things that you need to remember is that even if you changed something on the server (using ajax) it has no effect on the browser (unless you reload the page, or if your javascript code changes something). This is why you need to change (toggle/removeClass) inside the `done` function (exactly as in my answer)

Comment: @Dekel   I'm still not following. I wasn't trying to toggle `.isActive`.  I was trying to grab the `.isActive` element (via the `var element=$(this);` statement, and then use `element.closest...` to manipulate css and events further up the DOM. It was my understanding that `.done` should run on any ajax success, regardless of what the server passed back (I was returning an empty `Response` object in Symfony). I know that `.done` was running, because when I put in a `console.log()` it did return the element I was expecting.  My confusion was due to the `.css` and `.effect` commands not running.

Comment: @Dekel.  I do thank you for your assistance, however.  :)

Comment: Well, maybe I just didn't understand what exactly you wanted :)

Comment: @Dekel.  No worries.  the `.isActive` class was not meant to be a toggle, just a marker so I can find that element.  I should have perhaps named it better.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure :) you are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach will be following:

On server side, the route `/admin/toggleProgramActiv` should return `programId` as a response.
For example, it should send the JSON response like following:

```
{
  programId: '215546'
}
```

And then do in your js code, do following:

```
$(document).ready(function ()  {
    $(".isActive").on('click', function()  {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  "/admin/toggleProgramActive",
            data: {"id": $(this).data('program-id')}
        })
            .done(function(response) {
                var pid = response.programId;
                var element = $('a[data-program-id=' + pid + ']');

                element.removeClass('isActive');
                element.closest("tr").css('background-color', '#FF6600');
                element.closest("tbody").effect("highlight", {}, 600, function()  {
                    $(this).find("tr.bg-primary").css('background-color', "#337AB7")
                });
            })
    });
});
```

Also, make sure that you have `<tr>` tag in your html, which includes `<a>`, because I do not see any `<tr>` in your question.

Comment: ah... yes... edited in my tr.bg-primary and tbody into my HTML.

Comment: I had to do this: `var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);` before setting pid, but other than that, your approach worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @mcmurphy well, if you make sure you send json response on server side, and then add `dataType:"json"` to `$.ajax` configuration, then you do not have to do `JSON.parse` manually.

Answer (score 1):

The `a.isActive` element has a `click` event attached, and once you click on that element - the above function will be called.

In that function you run an ajax request (that sends data to the server - but doesn't change anything in the document), and therefor the `a.isActive` element will not change.

If you want - you can change the element (before the ajax call, or inside the `done` call - after the ajax call returned.

You can use the [toggleClass function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add/remove the `isActive` class from the element:

```
element.toggleClass('isActive')
```